# Implementing time slowdown in a multiplayer game

Tags: multiplayer, time-travel

My game has first-person melee combat that is based on directional attacks that are controlled with mouse gestures.  For example, a downward slash is most effectively blocked by a shield held up high.  I'd like to add a short "focus" mode while the player is holding down the mouse button to use their weapon/shield.  It should last no more than a second or so.

The problem is how to make this work when there are other players in the vicinity.  Nearby players shouldn't be slowed down or notice that the other player has slowed down time - it should look completely normal to them.  The players also need to be synchronized in "game time".  How can I do this?

Comment: What you're describing isn't really possible. You're talking about having two simultaneous time streams, running at different speeds, starting and ending at the same global time. You'd have to speed up the slow stream to catch up with the regular stream.

Comment: As Byte56 mentioned, you would have to speed up or slow down the simulation in one way shape or form. Depending on your client server architecture, this could be accomplished using clever client sync techniques to speed up certain activities after a "focus event", but this is a highly specialized thing that is 110% dependent on your multiplayer and game architecture, and thus there isn't enough context for any specific solution here. I would recommend looking into some of the latency mitigation techniques that some games use to mask the affects of a slow down, this could help sync the client.